# Qt creator: This application has failed to start because MSVCP110.dll was not found

Tags: windows, qt, qt-creator

Given that I downloaded the "`Qt 64bit version`" for my "`Windows Vista`", after the installation, the "`Qt Creator 2.7.0`" shows that it is based on "`Qt 5.0.2 (32bit)`". However, when creating a new project or opening an existing one, the following message appears:

- `This application has failed to start because MSVCP110.dll was not found`. note that the message box itself is titled "`uic.exe - Unable to locate Component`".

But when I click on "Ok" button, it creates the project (or opens it).

Why is this happening?

Comment: Your title is very unhelpful. It's almost like saying "I have a problem" or "Please help me" in the title. A good title is a one-sentence summary of the problem.

Comment: @sashoalm: Thanks for your advice. I wrote the previous title as I don't know the exact cause of my problem. How about now ?

Comment: Yes, it's better now. However, you seem to also have 2 questions - one about this error message, and one about you missing a compiler (you didn't install it?). You should have only 1 question per post. I'll remove the second part, but you can ask it in a separate post.

Answer (score 2):

Installing MSVC 2012 dlls should help: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Answer (score 0):

QT 5.0.2 64-bit need MSVC 2012. It uses MSVC 2012 compiler. If you have already installed try re-installing MSVC 2012. QT 5.0.2 32-bit version uses MSVC 2010. I feel this will help you.